# mvn spring-boot:run results in Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, spring-boot

Using XAMPP, I have a running a MySQL database and a Apacha web server running on my local machine.

I am executing the following Maven-command on my Spring boot based source code:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Then I am facing the following error message:

```
Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 28000
Error Code : 1045
Message    : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: This clearly shows username or password is incorrect ..

Comment: Are you sure your username and password combination is correct? try connecting it from SQL bench or some other client using the same credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The used password in Spring-boot and the default in MySQL were different.

You can find the default MySQL password in:

```
\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php
```

To be more specific, edit this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```